# How can I get a 2D sprite to slow to a stop?

Tags: sprite, godot, gdscript

I'm trying to create a playable sprite in Godot using GDScript. I've got my character moving left and right and then coming to a halt when no input is being pressed.

However, instead of coming to a dead stop, I want the sprite to slow down. How would I write that?

```
extends KinematicBody2D

var motion = Vector2()



func _physics_process(delta):

if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_right"):
    motion.x = 250


elif Input.is_action_pressed("ui_left"):
    motion.x = -250

else:
    motion.x = 0

move_and_slide(motion)

pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I figured it out:

```py
extends KinematicBody2D

var motion = Vector2()

func _physics_process(delta):

    if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_right"):
        motion.x = 250
    
    
    elif Input.is_action_pressed("ui_left"):
        motion.x = -250
    
    else:
        motion.x = motion.x * .9
    
    move_and_slide(motion)
```

Answer (score 0):

A very simple method is to dampen the speed at every update - a concept borrowed from physical drag.

```
extends KinematicBody2D
    var motion = Vector2()

func _physics_process(delta):
    if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_right"):
        motion.x = 250
    elif Input.is_action_pressed("ui_left"):
        motion.x = -250
    else:
        motion.x *= 0.95 # slow down by 5% each frame - play with this value
                         # i.e. make it dependent on delta to account for different fps
                         #      or slow down faster each frame
                         #      or clamp to zero under a certain threshold

    move_and_slide(motion)
    pass
```

Again this is very simple. To tune the drag value can be quite finicky if you want to give certain guarantees (like the player should come to a complete stop after 6 frames) especially when you're dealing with unlocked fps.

In such cases instead of having a single `motion` vector, have a `last_motion` and a `target_motion` vector and interpolate between them accordingly to get the current `motion` vector each frame (you can do this for acceleration too). This requires you to think about state transitions like "when a player stops pressing a button", starting timers to track the progress between the start and the target frame for the interpolation, etc... What [kind of interpolation function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation#Example) you choose will affect how responsive or sluggish the movement feels to the player.

Here's an example of slowing down within 0.2 seconds using linear interpolation:

```
enum MotionState {IDLE, MOVING, DECELERATING}

extends KinematicBody2D
    var state = IDLE
    var last_motion = Vector2()
    var time_motion = 0.0

func _physics_process(delta):
    var motion = Vector2();
    if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_right"):
        motion.x = 250
        state = MOVING
        last_motion = motion
    elif Input.is_action_pressed("ui_left"):
        motion.x = -250
        state = MOVING
        last_motion = motion
    elif state == IDLE
        motion.x = 0
    else:
        if state == MOVING:
            # start a smooth transition from MOVING through DECELERATING to IDLE
            state = DECELERATING
            # last_motion already holds last motion from latest MOVING state
            time_motion = 0.2
        # accumulate frame times
        time_motion -= delta
        if time_motion < 0.0:
            # reached last frame of DECELERATING, transitioning to IDLE
            state = IDLE
            motion.x = 0
        else:
            var t = (0.2 - time_motion) / 0.2 # t goes from 0 to 1
            # we're linearly interpolating between last_motion.x and 0 here
            motion.x = (1 - t) * last_motion.x

    move_and_slide(motion)
    pass
```

Linear deceleration will feel off, but you can easily replace that with any other function, e.g. try cubic for faster deceleration and thus more responsive slow-down: `motion.x = (1 - (t * t * t)) * last_motion.x`